# ONGRFilterBundle - Dynamic aggregate limit filters?

Tags: elasticsearch, ongr

How can I increase 10 options per filter defined as default.

```
ongr_filter_manager:
managers:
    # ...
filters:
    dynamic_attributes:
        type: dynamic_aggregate
        request_field: attributes
        document_field: attributes>attributes.value
        options:
            name_field: attributes.name
            show_zero_choices: false
```

Here is the documentation config, i need to get ALL options, not just 10.

Answer (score 0):

Add size option:

`...
        options:
            name_field: attributes.name
            show_zero_choices: false
            size: 20`